# Ice failed, add a TURN server and see about:webrtc for more details

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, mozilla, kurento

While trying to live video stream through Kurunto media server, I am facing issue while live streaming multiple users vide to the admin user through mozilla firefox, although it is working perfectly fine with the Chrome web browser. Below is the error while trying to get the live video feed of the user to admin user:

ice failed, add a TURN server and see about:webrtc for more details.

Below is the response on console in firefox:

Sending message: {"id":"onIceCandidate","candidate"
:{"candidate":"","sdpMid":"0","sdpMLineIndex":0,"usernameFragment":"b81d74b9"},"name":"mobcro"}

Also turn and coturn servers are already installed on my web server, if this will be the issue with the turn server it must not have to be work with chrome web browser also. FYI chrome and mozilla both are updated to the latest version and tried all the available methods as already mentioned on stackoverflow and other mediums.

Please help thanks in advance....

Comment: Looking  for the same, did you get any solution for this?

Comment: You can check for the turn server of yours if it is working or not using trickle site.